# Java jdbc batch insert only new rows

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, batch-insert

How can I efficiently perform a batch insert to a Sql Server table using jdbc only for new rows (ID column value not present in the target table)?

Actually I am using the [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) object to create the batches, but without the "insert only if new row" logic:

```
String sqlInsertStub = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)";

try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlInsertStub)) {

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    int processed = 0;

    while (resultSet.next()) {

        // [...]

        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, col2);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, col3);

        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        if (++processed % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
        }

    }

    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();    


catch (Exception e) {

    connection.rollBack();
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add a unique constraint on the three columns in your table which determine uniqueness.  Then, trying to insert a duplicate record should result in a Java exception.  But, this might cause an entire batch to fail.  If you want another option, you may change your query to the following:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable
                  WHERE id = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?);
```

To this query, you bind the values twice as follows:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
preparedStatement.setString(2, col2);
preparedStatement.setString(3, col3);
preparedStatement.setInt(4, id);
preparedStatement.setString(5, col2);
preparedStatement.setString(6, col3);
```

Comment: Could also use an [anonymous code block](https://pastebin.com/kNDXHBaL) to avoid having to pass the parameter values twice.

Comment: @GordThompson A row value constructor might be even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this other possible solution using merge:

```
String sqlInsertStub = "MERGE INTO mytable a USING (SELECT ? ID) b " +
                        "ON (a.ID = b.ID)" +
                        "WHEN NOT MATCHED " +
                        "THEN INSERT (ID, COL1, COL2) VALUES(b.ID, ?, ?)";
```